# Большой объем данных, вводимых пользователями

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте,хотелось бы обсудить с Вами один вопрос, возможно, глупый , но все же:

Представьте, что есть задача разработать сайт, который обрабатывает большое кол-во введенной информации, например что-то вроде таблиц вот такого масштаба:[ex](http://postimg.org/image/yjw0ab3kr/)

Это не вся таблица, полный её размер в заполненном варианте где-то около 120 строк * на 180 столбцов. И там есть 4 таблицы немного меньше.

Насколько целесообразно вообще оформлять эту задачу в виде сайта , а не например того же обычного десктоп приложения? Мне просто кажется, что такая задача как раз не подходит для её реализации в виде веб-решения как минимум по причине более медленного взаимодействия с БД сервера по сравнению с обычным приложением и большей трудоемкостью в процессе написания UI под все браузеры. Но очень хотелось бы услышать Ваше мнение по этому поводу.

Спасибо.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Если речь об отправке большого объема данных, то ничто не мешает отправлять данные на сервер по ячейкам/строкам/столбцам по мере их ввода.

Comment: Вопрос в том насколько целесообразно вообще оформлять эту задачу в виде сайта , а не например того же обычного десктоп приложения ?Просто на практике я пока не видел таких сайтов, которые бы обладали гуи для ввода такого большого кол-ва информации.

Comment: Если уж реализация требует чтобы интерфейс был бы доступен через URL (мало ли какие требования бывают), то как вариант, можно выполнить в виде Java-апплета. А вообще, повторю мнение автора ответа снизу - ввод должен быть отделен от формы отчета.

Comment: Если этим приложением будет пользоваться несколько учреждений одновременно и вопрос стоит о централизации данных, или как вариант оно может быть универсальным, то тут уместно говорить о Веб приложении. А если это одно учреждение с внутренней сетью, то я бы не стал заморачиваться с Веб, так как тут вопрос еще и в безопасности данных встанет, если это важно, разумеется.

Answer (score 4):

Вы лучше у пользователей узнайте, удобно им 180 колонок редактировать или нет? может быть им удобнее вводить данные по каждому параметру (или по 3-5-10) за раз и притом по каждой строке отдельно. таблица - это выходная форма чаще, чтоб было видно все и сразу. а при вводе скорее всего одновременно первый и второй семетр, например, вводить не будут и видеть их ни к чему вместе, и блоки строк с1 и с2 вводят разные люди и им тоже чужие разделы видеть ни к чему...
Хотя, сметы, вот, например тоже содержат 20-30 колонок, но люди привыкли простыни эти заполнять и все тут.

Веб или не веб, тут разницы нет особой, имхо - юзабельность можно поддержать примерно одинаково и там и там.

Скорость взаимодействия с базой тут отдельным пунктом должна быть (и не главным притом - см. далее). если десктопное приложение у вас будет толстым клиентом, то да, база получится как бы ближе и скорость типа выше. для веб-приложения получается у вас должна быть серверная часть (сервер приложений), который будет работать с базой - ну то, есть трехзвенка, дак она и в десктопных системах используется довольно часто.
Только тут реалтайма не надо  и 100к посетителей не будет же, вопрос взаимодействия с базой будет третьестепенным.

UI под разные браузеры - надуманная проблема. какой бы фреймворк вы не взяли, вы запросто можете ограничить пользователей хромом или фаерфоксом или ie (бывают там разные политики безопасности и т.д.), да и в большинстве случаев разница будет ничтожной.

Резюмирую. Задача может быть решена любым способом. Каким легче - это чисто ваш критерий.

Answer (score 0):

ввод данных отдельно. отчеты отдельно. и неважно десктоп или web